# batch file combine text from multiple files into one csv

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I saw this piece of code on a website that was a spin off of a previous stack overflow thread, however it is exactly what I'm trying to do utilizing batch. I have worked very little with batch and while it looks like it should produce the desired end result it's not doing quite what I would like, any and all help would be greatly appreciated. underneath the code I put an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
@echo off
set local EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    set i=0
for /F "delims=" %%l in (%%f) do (
    set /A i+=1
    set line!i!=%%l
)
echo %%f, !line1!, !line2!, !line3!, >> result.csv

text file 1    text file 2    text file 3 >> output.csv
1111,          2222,          3333           1111,2222,3333
1111,          2222,          3333           1111,2222,3333
1111,          2222,          3333           1111,2222,3333
1111,          2222,          3333           1111,2222,3333
```

Comment: What do you mean 'own column'? Do you mean if you have 3 files each with 10 columns, your output file will contain 30 columns? Please post an example

Comment: Each text file is one column I basically want to put those files together so the output file would be 3 colums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "tempfile=%temp%\tempfile.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

(
FOR %%f IN (
 q42500455_0.txt q42500455_1.txt q42500455_2.txt q42500455_3.txt q42500455_4.txt q42500455_5.txt
 ) DO FINDSTR /n /r "." "%sourcedir%\%%f"
)>"%tempfile%"

SET /a maxline=0
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1delims=:" %%a IN ("%tempfile%") DO IF %%a gtr !maxline! SET /a maxline=%%a

(
FOR /L %%L IN (1,1,%maxline%) DO (
 SET "line="
 FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ("%tempfile%") DO IF %%a==%%L (
  SET "line=!line!%%b"
 )
 ECHO !line!
)
)>"%outfile%"

DEL "%tempfile%" >NUL 2>nul

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used files named `q42500455*.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

The first `for` loop simply numbers each line from each of the files in the list and outputs the result to the temporary file (the name of which is irrelevant). The result is a file containing

```
1:line1 from file1
2:line2 from file1
...
1:line1 from file2
2:line2 from file2
...
```

The next `for` loop simply calculates the maximum line number used, tokenising the line number as `%%a` by using `:` as a delimiter.

The next section counts the line number into `%%L`, then builds the `line` from the matching line number in the tempfile. Since the tempfile contains line *n* in the order of file-specified, picking each line *n* and stringing them together will build the line as specified.

Note that I doubt your data as posted, which has terminal `,` on each line except for the last file. I believe that this `,` is missing and the procedure is expected to insert the `,`s as separators.

If this is so, then the changes required are:

```
...
  SET "line=!line!,%%b"
 )
 ECHO !line:~1!
...
```

to insert the comma, then `echo` all of the line bar the first character.

Comment: the last file does not have a , it is the last line in the file, but this is exactly what I needed I appreciate your response and thank you for the help.

Comment: the last line in the newly created file prints

11111111111111111:2222222222222222,22222222222222221:3333333333333333,3333333333333333 does this happen for you as well?

Comment: No. I'm presuming your files are #1 `111,` on each line; #2: `222,` on each line, #3: `333` on each line. Is there anything unusual about that last line of input? Do all 3 files have the same number of lines? Worked perfectly for me...

Comment: Okay thata fixed the issue a couple of the files had a different amount of lines, my next issue will be the source dir will not always be the same as different users will be logged in executing the script, is there another way to call the files specifically without setting the directory?

Comment: Certainly. Change `%sourcedir%\%%f` in the `findstr` to `"%%~f"` and specify the filenames with their full paths. If the full filename(s) contains spaces then "quote the full name". Quoting a full filename that does not contain spaces is not required, but does no harm. The list may be continued over a number of lines if required. There are other filename characters that may potentially cause problems - like `)&,;` - quoting such filenames should solve thos problems

Comment: would I need to set the directory if the file names are contained in the directory in which the script is running.

Comment: I don't know where the files are. If the are all in the same directory then all you need is to specify the filenames as in the posted code. If they are in the current directory (the directory in which the batch runs) then you can use simply `.` which means "current directory" - you can set this as `sourcedir` if you like - I use `sourcedir` habitually so I can test batch procedures. You can also use `cd directory` to change to a particular directory, or `pushd directoryname` which switches to the named directory and back again when a matching `popd` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

This method performs a direct merge file by file, adjusting lines when one file have less lines than the others.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Set the current directory where the Batch file is
cd "%~P0"

set "comma="
del result.csv 2>NUL
for %%f in (*.txt) do (

   rem If this is the first file
   if not exist result.csv (
      rem ... just copy it
      copy "%%f" result.csv > NUL

   ) else (

      rem Merge this file with previous one
      set "comma=!comma!,"
      move /Y result.csv result.in > NUL

      rem Read lines of previous file from Stdin
      < result.in (
      rem ... and combine they with this file
      for /F "usebackq delims=" %%l in ("%%f") do (
         set "line=!comma:~1!"
         set /P "line="
         echo !line!,%%l
      )

      rem If previous file is longer than this one, copy the rest of lines
      for /F "delims=" %%l in ('findstr "^"') do echo %%l,

      rem Combine previous output in new result file
      ) > result.csv

   )
)
del result.in
```