# Having text from a txt file be displayed side by side in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I have created a poker game in batch that displays the cards from .txt files. I use the following code to display them.

```
if %color% == orange type %card%of%suit%.txt & type %cardd%of%suitt%.txt
```

This works fine other than the cards are displayed one on top of the other like this:

```
 .------. 
 |A /\  |
 | /  \ |
 | \  / |
 |  \/ A|
 ^------^  
 .------. 
 |A /\  |
 | /  \ |
 | \  / |
 |  \/ A|
 ^------^
```

I want the cards to be displayed side by side like this:

```
 .------. .------. 
 |A /\  | |A /\  |
 | /  \ | | /  \ |
 | \  / | | \  / |
 |  \/ A| |  \/  |
 ^------^ ^------^
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42500455/batch-file-combine-text-from-multiple-files-into-one-csv/42501797#42501797 can easily be adapted to your desires

Comment: Sorry for being so ignorant but could you show me how Magoo? I do not see how that could be adopted to this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I slightly modified the code at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42500455/batch-file-combine-text-from-multiple-files-into-one-csv/42516842#42516842) to solve this problem, that is simpler in this case because all files have the same number of lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Example of use:
call :showCards %card%of%suit%.txt %cardd%of%suitt%.txt %carddd%of%suittt%.txt
goto :EOF


:showCards

rem Copy first card
copy %1 allCards.txt > NUL

:nextCard
shift
if "%~1" equ "" goto endCards

move /Y allCards.txt allCards.in > NUL

(
   rem Read lines of previous cards from Stdin
   rem and combine they with this card
   < allCards.in (for /F "usebackq delims=" %%l in ("%~1") do (
      set /P "line="
      echo !line!   %%l
   ))

rem Combine previous output in new output file
) > allCards.txt

goto nextCard
:endCards

type allCards.txt
exit /B
```

Note that a small modification is needed in case that the characters used in the cards include `!` exclamation marks or `^` carets.

Answer (score 1):

Using [batch file combine text from multiple files into one csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42500455/batch-file-combine-text-from-multiple-files-into-one-csv/42501797#42501797)

`sourcedir` is the directory containg your `%card%of%suit%.txt` files. This could be `.` or completely omitted if it's the current directory.

`destdir` you don't need as it's for an output directory

You don't specify what values you assign to `card` - presumably `card1..card5` (not limited) so I'm guessing now. The list of files would be

```
%card1%of%suit1%.txt %card2%of%suit2%.txt %card3%of%suit3%.txt %card4%of%suit4%.txt %card5%of%suit5%.txt .....
```

And since say if `card5` was unassigned this would generate an non-existent filename then `for %%f....) do IF EXIST findstr ...` to gate-out the `findstr` if the file did not exist.

`maxline` would probably be a constant (the number of lines in the file, which should all be the same and known) so this could be assigned directly and the `for ...%%a` assigning the value can be omitted.

Since you are not generating an output file, the `(` and `)>"outfile%"` that enclose the `FOR /L` loop need to be omitted - with the result that the `echo` will be directed to the screen as normal.

When building the line by appending `%%b`, it you will probably want to insert a space between the `!` and the `%%b`. If you do this, `line` will acquire a leading space when the first  is added, so you may want to remove that leading space, which can be done by `echo`ing `!line:~1!`

So - simple, methodical adjustment. I've used 5 as #of cards, but there's no  limit in principle - just screenwidth available.

Comment: the variables %card% and %suit% are randomly generated I have 52 txt files already created with the "graphics" for the cards in them.  I dont know if that is useful information or not but this answer just seems far too complicated for my purposes